# Can I modify Datatables PDF button to print table info and in landscape?

Tags: pdf, datatables

I have print, PDF and Excel buttons on my datatable.  The table has quite a few columns, is there a way to create the PDF in Landscape?  Also, is there a way to print the table info (re: Showing x to y of z)?

Comment: Doesn't this mainly depend on what software you are using?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... I am using dataTables with the Buttons extension... had to include pdfmake for the PDF button to work.  Here's a link to what I downloaded... it works, I just want to change the pdf from portrait to landscape... <https://datatables.net/download/#bs/jszip-2.5.0,pdfmake-0.1.18,dt-1.10.8,b-1.0.1,b-html5-1.0.1,b-print-1.0.1,fh-3.0.0,rr-1.0.0 *>

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work for me ( I use button extensions)

```
"buttons": [
    {
       extend: 'pdfHtml5',
       orientation: 'landscape',
       pageSize: 'LEGAL'
    }
]
```

[PDF - page size and orientation](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/pdfPage.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're using the [TableTools extension](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/) for DataTables to enable saving as PDF. If not, get it and use it. From there, it's pretty simple. Here's an example:

**With TableTools extension**:

```
"tableTools": {
   {
      "sExtends":"pdf",
      "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
   }
}
```

**With Buttons extension** (DataTables 1.10.8+):

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'pdf',
            text: 'Save as PDF',
            exportOptions: {
                modifier: {
                    orientation:'landscape'
                }
            }
        }
    ]
} );
```

Comment: I'm not using TableTools as that's been retired.  I used the datatables download builder to select the options I need:     <https://datatables.net/download/#bs/jszip-2.5.0,pdfmake-0.1.18,dt-1.10.8,b-1.0.1,b-html5-1.0.1,b-print-1.0.1,fh-3.0.0,rr-1.0.0
 *> which include pdfmake for the PDF button.

Comment: Edited answer with version not using TableTools.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!  Orientation doesn't seem to be an export option.  I got it working with the following:
`$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#instrumentsTable').dataTable({ stateSave: true,
            autoWidth: true, dom: 'Bfirtip', buttons: ['print', { extend: 'pdf', orientation: 'landscape' }  , 'excel'],
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0] },
                { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [0] }]
        }).columnFilter(... `

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I've always used TableTools and the new version is...well...new to me a bit. The code you have is VERY similar to how TablesTools does it actually.

Answer (score 1):

I answered my question in a comment... thought I should probably post an official answer:
I am not using TableTools as that's been retired.  I used the following site to build the .js and .css files I use:  https://datatables.net/download/#bs/jszip-2.5.0,pdfmake-0.1.18,dt-1.10.8,b-1.0.1,b-html5-1.0.1,b-print-1.0.1,fh-3.0.0,rr-1.0.0

I got it working with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#instrumentsTable').dataTable({
        stateSave: true,
        autoWidth: true,
        dom: 'Bfirtip',
        buttons: [
          'print', {
            extend: 'pdf',
            orientation: 'landscape'
          },
          'excel'
        ],
        "aoColumnDefs": [{
          "bSortable": false,
          "aTargets": [0]
        }, {
          "bSearchable": false,
          "aTargets": [0]
        }]
      }).columnFilter(...etc)
```

Hope this is helpful to someone!
~~~Tracy

Comment: What about the table 'info'? Could you include it to your PDF output?

Answer (score 0):

this can also work....

```
#check <<extend: "pdfHtml5" >> for pdf

buttons: [
                {
                  extend: "copy",
                  className: "btn-sm"
                },
                {
                  extend: "csv",
                  className: "btn-sm"
                },
                {
                  extend: "excel",
                  className: "btn-sm"
                },
                {
                  extend: "pdfHtml5",
                  className: "btn-sm",
                  orientation: 'landscape'
                },
                {
                  extend: "print",
                  className: "btn-sm"
                },
              ]
```